# Flutter DropdownMenu wont update current selection

Tags: flutter, dart, drop-down-menu

I've seen how this is supposed to be done in the docs; what's wrong in the setStae, what am I missing? Thank you!

```dart
String dropdownValue;

Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  child: DropdownButton<String>(
                    hint: Text('Choose your Server'),
                    value: dropdownValue,
                    onChanged: (newValue) {
                      setState(() {
                        dropdownValue = newValue;
                        print(dropdownValue);
                      });
                    },
                    items: kServers.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String val) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                        value: val,
                        child: Text(val),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                  ),
                ),
```

Comment: How does `kServers` look like?

Comment: Also the `value` right below the *hint* property isn't needed

Comment: I think the vlaue is essential

Comment: give it an initial value to your "dropdownValue" variable. note that it should be one of the values in your kServer Strings. see if that works.

Comment: Adding a value to the String made no difference. kServers do show up in the list tho.

List<String> kServers = [
  'Adamantoise',
  'Aegis',
  'Alexander'
];

Comment: Could it be because kServers is in another class?  o.o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out how to do it. Just wrap it in a StatefulWidget.